# PayPal cancels payment when credit card was not accepted

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I´m trying to use PayPal Plus on my website. But the error handling is horrible. If I choose the credit card payment option and provide all input correctly, everything works fine.
But there are some circumstances where PayPal cancels the payment without a meaningful message.

1) I open my payment site and choose a payment method (credit card or direct debit).

2) I get to the PayPal site for providing the credit card or bank number.

3) Some test accounts cannot be used for credit card or direct debit payment (they need special confiuration). In this case, an error message is shown "You cannot use your credit card for this payment", and I am able to correct the input. So, I use the information of a valid test account.

4) When I submit the payment, I am redirected to the "cancel_url". Usually, the user is redirected to the cancel-url, if the user cancels the payment. But I submitted the payment.
Additionally, an additional url parameter "ppp_msg=1" is set.

```
http://localhost:8080/myCancelUrl/?token=EC-XYZ&ppp_msg=1
```

But I cannot find anything about this beaviour or the ppp_msg parameter in the docs!

Is it a PayPal Bug? Or is it simply because I used a misconfigured test account? Could this also happen in live environment?

**Edit:**

This is the payment object after the payment was "approved", but canceled by PayPal:

```
{
    "id": "PAY-5NW72433139862519LBBL3ZQ",
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal",
        "status": "UNVERIFIED",
        "payer_info": {
            "email": "bla.blubb@web.com",
            "first_name": "test",
            "last_name": "user",
            "payer_id": "X2JJSLSRYALK8",
            "country_code": "DE"
        }
    },
    "cart": "2L623830BF080064T",
    "transactions": [{
        "related_resources": [],
        "amount": {
            "currency": "EUR",
            "total": "10.00"
        },
        "payee": {
            "email": "test-facilitator@web.de"
        }
    }],
    "state": "created",
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://localhost:8080/executePayment.html?paymentId\u003dPAY-5NW72433139862519LBBL3ZQ",
        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:8080/cancelPayment.html"
    },
    "create_time": "2016-12-03T12:43:18Z",
    "update_time": "2016-12-03T12:44:28Z",
    "links": [...]
}
```

The user is marked as unverified, but I used a verified account. It seems that this breaks the whole thing.

Comment: Post some code ... We cannot know what's the issue without seeing the source ... Have you tried debugging your code to find out why are you being redirected to the cancel URL ?

Comment: There is nothing I could debug. I just create a payment object - always the same way. Everything else is PayPal logic.

Comment: what is the paypal context parameter that you are passing, and what is the content of the created payment after the call, are you getting any exceptions during the payment ?

Comment: I just give the client-id, client-secret, and api-mode (sandbox) as parameters to the PayPal context. I didn´t check if the payment object has changed. - good suggestion - I will check this.

Comment: Yeah check for the contents of the payment object and what it returns ... Post the updates here :)